# Is there a way to see if someone is using device?

Tags: windows, networking

I have a USB digital certificate being shared by some collaborators using [USB-over-Network](http://www.usb-over-network.com/). This simulates a connection between the server's usb-port and the client's OS. I have a server in a room with the device connected in it, and another room with the collaborators doing their stuff.

However, only one client can use this at a time. So, if a collaborator doesn't "disconnect" the device, he will have the connection open for the entire day, even if he's not using it. This way, no other person can use the device only because the person already connected to it "don't want to share it" because he will have to ask to use it again.

So, my question is: is there a way to check who is using this device, and for how long it has been in idle? I don't want to disconnect someone actively using it. 30~40 minutes or so of USB inactivity is the amount of time I'm willing to consider before entering idle state.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Maybe wireshark can help with this? To monitor the network and see who is using, when were the last time used, and the purpose (to access the site, upload a file, and so on...). I have never used wireshark before though.

Comment: What OS is the server running? On Linux depending on the type and use case usually `lsof` , `netstat` or `ss` will show such open file-handlers/connections

Comment: @HBruijn It is running a normal windows 10, nothing fancy.

Comment: Not all social problems can be solved with technology. These people who are supposed to be collaborating yet won't share this USB device with each other need a stern talking-to from their own manager.